# Skimage resize function returns black images

Tags: resize, scikit-image

I'm trying to resize some images that I've loaded using matplotlib's imread function. 
An example:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(imgs[0])
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, when I try to apply the resize function and then replot:

```
def rescale_image(img):
    """Rescale the jpg range of 0-255 to 0-1"""
    img = resize(img, (100, 100), anti_aliasing=True)
    return img /255
#imgs = [rescale_image(i) for i in imgs]

io = rescale_image(imgs[0])
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(io)
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

The result is: 
[image]

Why?

UPDATE: The import statements:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import imread
from skimage.transform import resize


imgs = [imread(p) for p in paths_list]# paths list is generated by glob.glob on the folder of images
```

Comment: Please show your `import` statements so we know what modules you are using, and also show how you open the image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've updated the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image starts out with pixels in the range 0..1. When you resize it, you divide by 255, so the range is now 0..0.003 so it looks black.

**Solution?**

Change this line:

```
return img /255
```

to this:

```
return img
```

Comment: Sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes!